# vendor/lineage/build/soong/Android.bp:24:8: module "generated_kernel_includes": cmd: unknown variable '$(PATH_OVERRIDE_SOONG)'

Tags: android-source, lineageos, custom-rom

Hi There i'm newbie in building rom and im facing this error while building ricedroid (Android 13) for Mi A1 (tissot):-

```
[100% 1/1] analyzing Android.bp files and generating ninja file at out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp
error: vendor/lineage/build/soong/Android.bp:24:8: module "generated_kernel_includes": cmd: unknown variable '$(PATH_OVERRIDE_SOONG)'
16:51:54 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (30 seconds) ####
```

Any idea how do i solve this issue

As i got one result on lineageos gerrit to change

```
PATH_OVERRIDE_SOONG := $(shell echo $(TOOLS_PATH_OVERRIDE))
```

in config/BoardConfigSoong.mk
but issue remains same

Comment: Try `breakfast tissot` first

Comment: What if `breakfast` command is not found?

Comment: @zinger , you need to invoke "source build/envsetup.sh" from the working directory root first, to get all the custom variables and functions running.

Answer (score 0):

This is a device tree adaptation problem. You just need to do a
`breakfast <devicecodename>`
and the error that it throws will automatically tell you what filename that your `lineage_devicecodename.mk` should have...
In my case, I had the same problem, when I'm trying with `ricedroid_avicii.mk`, but the actual string I should have was `lineage_avicii.mk`
After adapting my device tree (Android.mk, common lunch choices, rom.dependencies, etc,) then PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES successfully took all the directories that it needed.

In your case you need to modify it to **lineage_tissot** in `<something>_tissot.mk` (the file name will be different for each device trees. Just look for `<something>_tissot.mk` file.) and AndroidProducts.mk file. Also rename that `<something>_tissot.mk` to `lineage_tissot.mk`

Feel free to ask your question regarding building roms.
Hope you understand my guide.
Thank You✨

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue and solved it by executing `source build/envsetup.sh` and then `make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh`.